# Can you use Swift with React Native

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-ios

Does anyone know if it’s possible to develop a fully Native iOS and Android based Social Media Platform using React Native and Swift or Objective C to integrate a native instant messenger app into the newsfeed via a floating icon?

Our website is responsive and would make a great hybrid app using a native wrap but we are looking to stray away from web based solutions and want to try and build a fully native solution with React Native and possible Swift or Objective C. We discovered a decent IM sdk that is feature rich but is written in Objective C and Swift and wish to use this [Instant Messaging Solution](http://relatedcode.com/premium) and attempt to match chat graphics with the rest of the app.

All thoughts, ideas and solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write code in `Objective-C/Swift` or `Java` for developing your own modules and to take advantage of native API for iOS or Android. But `React-Native` has some build-on modules that would simplify your workd just by writing `JavaScript` and that the *magic* of React-Native. It makes possible to build Apps in JavaScript  that use real native elements and not just WebViews.

If you need to write your own modules in `Objective-C/Swift` or `Java` you should make use of the Bridge that implements `React-Native` for sharing data between Native-Code and Javascript code.

"*Sometimes an app needs to access a platform API and React Native doesn't have a corresponding module yet. Maybe you want to reuse some existing Objective-C, Swift or C++ code without having to reimplement it in JavaScript, or write some high performance, multi-threaded code such as for image processing, a database, or any number of advanced extensions*." from [React-Native oficial website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios)

Comment: Thank you for that. I’ll try and figure it out. I don’t have any programmers to work with and this is kind of a side project for me for fun.

Comment: @Them perfect! it is really nice! do you have any budget for your "project "?

Comment: Nothing concrete but between these two it’s only $200 and that’s leave me with a decent amount of elbow room lol

Comment: if you are interessed i could create a prototyp for you.

Comment: Yea sure. Message me, I’m not too sure how to you as a friend on here yet. It’s quite complicated.

Comment: I sent an email